# how to get the last inserted mail in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the error in db

> object reference is required to access non-static member in db

My method

```
public static object GetOrderEmail(List<Lunch> lunch1)
{         
   StringBuilder email = new StringBuilder();

   string text = "";

   foreach (var lunch in lunch1)
   {              
      Lunch lun = db.Lunch.OrderByDescending(p => p.Email).FirstOrDefault().Email;
      email.AppendFormat(lunch.Email);

      text = lunch.Email;
   }

   return text;
 }
```

Comment: It's quite simple. The field `Lunch` in `db` is not static and you're trying to access it like db.Lunch. Either make it static or create an instance of db.

Comment: can you show us definition of db and definition of Lunch